Failed to start fboxdrv.service Ubuntu 24.04
Failed to start vboxdrv.service (there are two other failures as well):

All I can do is interact with the command line using ctrl alt f3.
I tried sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and got back unmet dependencies, which suggested that I apt —fix-broken install, but when I try to run that command it says there are running VMs found and they must be closed.
